# Unexpected behavior when "using" is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can I use user defined type, say a class inside using block ? When I used:

1. It said, I need to inherit IDisposable and implement Dispose method. I inherited and tried to define Dispose method, I couldn't. It shows me its not public or something :( Please help me understand this with a small code on how can I achieve it.
2. If I create an instance of a class inside the "using" brackets, although the scope of this variable is only within that using block, why the heck I cannot create another instance of the same class with the same variable outside the using ? I see no good reason for that :( Is my reasoning correct ? But I could use the same variable for instantiating another class outside the using(Is that ok to do ? As I see no compile errors), although I am well aware that we should practise coding guideline (But conceptually I am seeking logic)....

Please help, I am new to C#

Comment: +1 WRT to point 2, there is a group of people (including me) that does not agree with the limited lexical scoping of C#. This will probably never change.

Comment: What exactly is the "strange" behavior your title refers to?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, may be I need to correct my title, really unsure how can I correct the title...sorry for using "strange" word.

Comment: @Divine: Hit the "edit" button on your post

Answer (score 8):

The whole point of the `using` statement is to call the `Dispose` method specified in the `IDisposable` interface.

And yes, when implementing an interface, either the method needs to be public or you need to use explicit interface implementation:

```
// Via a public method
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}

// Via explicit interface implementation
public class Bar : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

There's nothing specific about `IDisposable` here - it's just normal interface implementation.

You shouldn't implement `IDisposable` just for the sake of it though - the idea is that it should be cleaning up for you - if you don't have any clean-up to perform, you don't need the `using` statement either.

As for the second point: you're simply not allowed to declare a local variable with the same name as another local variable which is still in scope. It would be very confusing to read, hence it's prohibited. From section 8.5.1 of the C# spec:

> The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable. Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name.

Note that you *can* still have the same local variable name twice in one method, provided they're not both in scope at the same time:

```
void M()
{
    using (Stream x = ...)
    {
    }

    using (Stream x = ...)
    {
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
    }

    // Block introduced just for scoping...
    {
        string x = "";
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jon Skeet. Well your first point now gave me no compile error, great. But I am wondering or dont understand, how should I achieve the same inbuilt cleaning process which is similar to when I use this "using" for sql connection, I call the methodname.Dispose() in finally. Meaning, I understand that the SQL class has given some implementation in that inbuilt ? Cant I use something same without me cwriting code for cleaning ? In this case preferably where I use user defined class... ?

Comment: @Divine: It's not at all clear what you mean. A `using` statement is absolutely equivalent to calling `Dispose` in a `finally` block - except it's easier to read and maintain. I have no idea whether the type that you're writing even *needs* any clean-up code... but if it does, you need to write that yourself. It's not clear which SQL class you're even talking about, but if it's something which implements `IDisposable`, it will include appropriate code to clean up its resources.

Comment: Also, as far second point is concerned, well I now used the same variable for instantiating another class, it gives me error :( Well I completely understand coding guidelines as you say and readability point of view, but I am trying to understand, the variable in using scope is only between { and } right ? Meaning, I cant use that variable outside using scope and even if I use, it gives me exception ? Right ? Why cant I use the same variable name atleast for different class instantiation ? :(

Comment: @Divine: It doesn't give you an exception, it gives you a compile-time error. Exceptions are very different. You can't use the same variable name because it would be confusing - the language is trying to protect you from yourself. It's bad enough when you've got a local variable and an instance variable called the same thing - having two local variables in scope with the same name at the same time would be even worse.

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you so much for your detailed way of using variables. but the scope of variable I am trying to understand is    using(Class c = new Class())    {    }; // here, c's scope is only inside using right ? then why cant I reuse  derived c = new derived(); ?????

Comment: Regarding SQL class, its SQLConnection which inherits DbConnection. But hey one more observation I found here is, DbConnection doesnt implement Dispose() method although its deriving from IDisposable interface. I then saw in SQLConnectionclass, where it just have this statement protected override void Dispose(bool disposing); apart from other methods. May I know where its body is defined ? Without defining body, how its cleaning ??? :( Also my one more question is, a class need not implement a interface method but can be implemented in derived class like in this case ?

Comment: @Divine: You can't declare `c` outside the `using` statement because then the scope of `c` is the whole of the surrounding block - so the declaration *inside* the `using` statement is invalid. `DbConnection` itself is an abstract class - while it *could* take responsibility for delegating to `Close`, it makes more sense to let the concrete class do it. So `SqlConnection` itself is likely to be the class which *really* provides the clean-up code. I'm afraid I don't understand your last question - but I would suggest you ask it in a separate SO question anyway, having worked out how to phrase it

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for the reply, I was worried why I shouldn't have c outside { and }.....As one of the folk pointed out above, my question is limited lexical scoping. Well Let me leave this as homework for me to understand better using your inputs...

Comment: Jon, well regarding abstract class thing, I did a small program     public abstract class A : IDisposable    {}; public Class B : A { protected override void Dispose(bool disposing); }    Why it gives me error ? I did similar to DbConnection and SQLConnection class how it implement IDisposable right :(

Comment: Jon, I now realize that, here " DbConnection : Component, IDbConnection, IDisposable" Component class implements "Dispose" method. Why then they have to implement IDisposable in DbConnection ? And I don't see any implementation for that Dispose method in DbConnection but concrete class SqlConnection. Why I am getting compile time error when I design similar classes ? :(

Comment: @Divine: As I've said before, you're now into a completely different territory - you should ask another question, but focus very carefully on asking it *well*.

Comment: Hi Jon, sure, thank you very much for helping me through :) I appreciate it much.